# Using Kryonet with Libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, kryonet

Hi so I know how to use Kyronet and libgdx but what I want to know is when installing the Kyronet library do I only have to copy it into the Main project folder or do I have to put it in the Android and Desktop folders as well or do I have to do that attach source with?

I'm only asking here cause I can't find any documentation on installing Kryonet and want to cover all of my bases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never used *kryonet*, but if it's no android native components dependent, it's ok if you just import it in your main project.

Regarding including source code, there's no need unless you're planning to make frequent changes to it.

Answer (score 1):

In my previous projects, I've had to add it to the build paths of both the Main project and the Android project.